# Azure queues Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, azure

I have problem retrieve Azure messages from Queue on Windows Phone 7.

To add message I am using such code:

```
var queueClient =  CloudStorageContext.
                       Current.
                       Resolver.
                       CreateCloudQueueClient() as CloudQueueClient;
var queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("queuein");

queue.Create(
    r => queue.AddMessage(
             new CloudQueueMessage { AsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg) },
             c =>
             {
                 // Some logic here.
             }));
```

To get message back it looks like I have to follow similar principle and use queue instance.
But `GetMessage()` method has VOID return type:

[image: Print screen of issue]

Could you guys help me to understand what the hell is going on in Mobile version of Azure queues, because in Windows console application those methods has return type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Async patterns are a bit different on the phone.  You need to handle the message in the callback function.

```
    ShowAmWorkingInUILol = true;      
    // snip
    queue.GetMessage(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), OnMessageReturned);
}

private void OnMessageReturned(CloudOperationResponse<CloudQueueMessage> response)
{
    ShowAmWorkingInUILol = false;
    // here's your response.
}
```

Comment: The intellisense had the answer. :)